# who return value in bourne-shell

Tags: scripting, sh

hi I am trying to write a bourne-shell script that takes a name as a parameter and check if the user is logged in and output a message if not.

this is what I got so far but my condition is wrong.

```
if test "who|grep $1" == "$1" //the problem is that it takes the hole 1st column
then 
  who|grep $1|awk '{print $5}'
else
  echo user not logged in
fi
```

any help? thanks in advance.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Does that include the race condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your condition is completely fouled up.

2) Your regex is inaccurate.

3) You're mixing grep and awk.

4) You're not quoting your `echo` argument.

```
if who | grep -q "^$1\s"
then 
  who | awk -v user="$1" '$1 == user { print $5 }'
else
  echo "user not logged in"
fi
```

Replacing the first `grep` with `awk` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: +1: For pointing out there's no need to mix `grep` and `awk` [the replacement exercise ahas already been done ;)] and for putting `user` into a variable, I've edited my answer to incorporate that.

Comment: I tried your code but it always prints `user not logged in` if it's not too much asked can you explain your condition please?

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use `who` and `awk`:

```
who | awk -v user="$1" '
$1 == user {
    found = 1
    print $5
}

END {
    if (!found) {
        print "user not logged in"
    }
}'
```

Personally, I would just use [**`finger`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/finger).

Answer (score 3):

A few notes here.

1) Use [ instead of test -- test is just an alias for it. ( [ is not syntax, it is the name of a program.)

2) // is not a comment in the shell. :)  Similarly, things in ""s, like "who|grep..." will not be executed, they're going to be treated like literals by the shell.

3) start by doing who | grep ... | awk to extract a particular column.

4) You can capture the output of 3) by doing something like

VARIABLE=$(who | ... )

5) THEN, you can do if [ -z "$VARIABLE" ] or something.

6) Alternatively, check if who | fgrep -w ... | wc -l yields more than zero.

There are probably a dozen other ways to swing this.

Comment: what do you mean by 6) ? sorry I just started b-shell

Comment: if the column has for exemple 3 rows how would capture only the third row of the first column?\

Comment: by 6) I mean, use wc -l to count lines of output from your grep. read the wc man page for details. I do not understand your second question in the context of seeing if a user is logged in.

Comment: because I tried to use finger but then `finger -s username|awk '{print $1}' prints the hole 1st column which is `login username`
but I only want to print username

Comment: Why recommend [ over test?  test is far more readable, and the world would be a better place if [ had never been used as an alias for test.

Comment: No, `if test` is much less readable than `if [ ... ]` -- if you read S.R. Bourne's original paper about the shell, he barely even mentions "test". In particular, the use of "test" makes the intent of the operation much less manifest.